# Edges look wrong when compositing layer with blur and transparency

Tags: after-effects, compositing, alpha

I'm trying to composite layers from an animation I made with Blender in After Effects. The problem I'm running into is that the motion-blurred edges are either receding, or becoming discolored, depending on the settings I choose.

I'm using a 32bit OpenEXR Multilayer file and the EXtractoR plug-in to select the layers. I'm also using Color Profile Converter.

For whatever reason, the edges look more accurate when UnMult is checked, but the colors get messed up.

Pictured below is the combined render (from Blender), which I'm using as the basis to compare my composite to. Beneath that is how my composite looks without, and then with UnMult checked.

[image: Combined render straight from Blender with all objects turned on.]
[image: Composite of foreground and background renders in Adobe After Effects with UnMult unchecked.]
[image: Composite of foreground and background renders in Adobe After Effects with UnMult checked.]